# How to enable retention period for blobs using Dynamic Provisioning

Tags: azure-devops

I have used dynamic provisioing (PVC uses nfs premium inbuilt storage class ), that automatically creates Storage account, Storage container and PV is mounted on Kubenetes pod mountPath. Below is the PVC file, which generate storage account, PV and container. Basically I wanted to mount blob. Its working fine. But now I want to set retention period like 30days for the blob, after which the file should be deleted. How to automate this ? Where to implement this ? I was reading about immutable storage life cycle configurations, But mine is not immutable, the container will keep on be written by uploading blobs.

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      name: azure-blob-storage-pvc
      namespace: example
      annotations:
          volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: azureblob-nfs- 
    premium
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteMany
      storageClassName: blob
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

I have given this as in helm templates and deploying the pod with Volume Mount.